# Can you cache url under some custom key using Fresco?

Tags: android, fresco

I would like to cache url using Fresco but I need to cache it under some key, tag or something and retrieve it using that key or tag. Is it possible doing that using fresco?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a custom CacheKeyFactory which takes an ImageRequest, which you can then use to create cache keys for.

```
CacheKeyFactory myFactory = new CacheKeyFactory() {
  @Override
  public CacheKey getBitmapCacheKey(ImageRequest request, Object callerContext) {
    // your logic goes here
    return new BitmapMemoryCacheKey(
        getCacheKeySourceUri(request.getSourceUri()).toString(),
        request.getResizeOptions(),
        request.getRotationOptions(),
        request.getImageDecodeOptions(),
        null,
        null,
        callerContext);
  }

}
ImagePipelineConfig.Builder builder = ...
builder.setCacheKeyFactory(myFactory);

Fresco.initialize(c, builder.build());
```

Default implementation: https://github.com/facebook/fresco/blob/cc75c37eb777b000426a2373312e3b143c8ed9f7/imagepipeline/src/main/java/com/facebook/imagepipeline/cache/DefaultCacheKeyFactory.java